# Resizing all elements in JavaFX GUI using Java Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, autoresize, stage, scene, scenebuilder

I'm building a project in javaFx and using scene builder to create and manage my GUI.

I want the stage to be resizable and when it the user resizes the window I want all elements to resize accordingly and automatically.

Another thing is I want the stage window to resize according to the scene size automatically.

I use `Anchor Pane` as my root node in all scenes. 
 
What I get right now when resizing the window is the window frame going over the content of the window but doesn't affect it.

Here is the controller class for the specific scene:

```
![package screensframework;

import GameEngine.Player;
import GameEngine.PlayerActions;
import GameEngine.PlayerType;
import GameEngine.Table;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class TableSceneController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {

    private ScreensController myController;
    private GameEngine.Table myTable;
    private int playerNumber;
    private int betindex;
    private SimpleBooleanProperty standPossible;
    private SimpleBooleanProperty hitPossible;
    private SimpleBooleanProperty doublePossible;
    private SimpleBooleanProperty splitPossible;

    @FXML
    private Button standButton;
    @FXML
    private Button hitButton;
    @FXML
    private Button splitButton;
    @FXML
    private Button doubleButton;
    @FXML
    private Button placeBetButton;
    @FXML
    private Label messageLabel;
    @FXML
    private Slider betSlider;

    @FXML
    private GridPane betGridPane;

    @FXML
    private Label betLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label Player1Money;
    @FXML
    private Label Player2Money;
    @FXML
    private Label Player3Money;
    @FXML
    private Label Player4Money;
    @FXML
    private Label Player5Money;
    @FXML
    private Label Player6Money;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        standPossible = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        hitPossible = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        doublePossible = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        splitPossible = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        splitPossible.set(false);
        doublePossible.set(false);
        hitPossible.set(false);
        standPossible.set(false);

        getDoublePossible().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> source, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                setDoubleButton(newValue);
            }
        });

        getHitPossible().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> source, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                setHitButton(newValue);
            }
        });

        getSplitPossible().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> source, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                setSplitButton(newValue);
            }
        });

        getStandPossible().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> source, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                setStandButton(newValue);
            }
        });

        betSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
                betLabel.textProperty().setValue(String.valueOf((int) betSlider.getValue()));
            }

        });

        playerNumber = 0;
        betindex = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {
        myController = screenParent;
    }

    @FXML
    public void onHit(ActionEvent event) {
        myTable.hit(playerNumber, betindex);
        dealCardsAnimation();
        checkStillInGame();
    }

    @FXML
    public void onStand(ActionEvent event) {
        checkStillInGame();

    }

    @FXML
    public void onDouble(ActionEvent event) {
        myTable.playDouble(playerNumber, betindex);
        dealCardsAnimation();
        checkStillInGame();
    }

    @FXML
    public void onSplit(ActionEvent event) {
        myTable.split(playerNumber, betindex);
        dealCardsAnimation();
    }

    @FXML
    public void onPlaceBet(ActionEvent event) {
        myTable.getPlayersOnTable().get(playerNumber).AddBet((int) betSlider.getValue());
        betSlider.setValue(1);
        checkIfthereAreMorePlayersToBet();

    }

    public void checkIfthereAreMorePlayersToBet() {
        if (playerNumber + 1 < myTable.getNumberOfPlayers()) {
            playerNumber++;
            getBets();
        } else {
          //  messageLabel.textProperty().set("");
            //betGridPane.disableProperty().set(true);
            // myTable.dealCardsToPlyers();
            //dealCardsAnimation();
            startPlay();
        }
    }

    private void setStandButton(boolean value) {
        standButton.disableProperty().setValue(value);
    }

    private void setHitButton(boolean value) {
        hitButton.disableProperty().setValue(value);
    }

    private void setSplitButton(boolean value) {
        splitButton.disableProperty().setValue(value);
    }

    private void setDoubleButton(boolean value) {
        doubleButton.disableProperty().setValue(value);
    }

    private void dealCardsAnimation() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void startPlay() {
        for (Player player : myTable.getPlayersOnTable()) {
            System.out.println(player.getBet(0).getSumOfBet());
        }

//        standPossible.set(myTable.isActionPossible(playerNumber, betindex, PlayerActions.STAND));
//        hitPossible.set(myTable.isActionPossible(playerNumber, betindex, PlayerActions.HIT));
//        doublePossible.set(myTable.isActionPossible(playerNumber, betindex, PlayerActions.DOUBLE));
//        splitPossible.set(myTable.isActionPossible(playerNumber, betindex, PlayerActions.SPLIT));
    }

    private void endRound() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void checkStillInGame() {
        if (!myTable.isHandInPlay(playerNumber, betindex)) {
            if (myTable.getPlayerHand(playerNumber).size() - 1 > betindex) {
                betindex++;
                startPlay();

            } else if (playerNumber + 1 == myTable.getNumberOfPlayers()) {
                endRound();
            } else {
                playerNumber++;
                betindex = 0;
                startPlay();
            }
        }
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty getStandPossible() {
        return standPossible;
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty getHitPossible() {
        return hitPossible;
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty getDoublePossible() {
        return doublePossible;
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty getSplitPossible() {
        return splitPossible;
    }

    private void getBets() {
        if (myTable.getPlayersOnTable().get(playerNumber).getType() == PlayerType.HUMAN) {
            updateMessageLabel(" please enter your bet.");
            placeBetButton.disableProperty().setValue(false);
            betSlider.setMax(myTable.getPlayersOnTable().get(playerNumber).getSumOfMoney());
            betSlider.setMin(1);
        }else{
            myTable.placeComputerBet(playerNumber);
            checkIfthereAreMorePlayersToBet();
        }

    }

    private void updateMessageLabel(String message) {
        messageLabel.textProperty().set(myTable.getPlayersOnTable().get(playerNumber).getName() + message);

    }

    @Override
    public void onShow() {

        myTable.startNewRound();
        getBets();

    }

    @Override
    public void setMyTable(GameEngine.Table myTable) {
        this.myTable = myTable;
    }

}
```

Comment: `AnchorPane` will automatically `resize` according to the `Scene size` ! May be we are missing something. An `image` or `code snippets` would be of great help !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I added the controller class for the scene and also tried to add a screenshot (no success there). Hope you could help